# Display value of second gridview from first gridview

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table:

**Box**:

```
id (int)
totalDimension (double)
usedDimension (double)
```

and on an aspx page I have a gridview that bind to this table by using:

```
 Select id, (totalDimension- usedDimension) AS available From Box;
```

[image]

When the user clicks "select" of a particular row of the gridview, another gridview would appear and show other box that have usedDimension lesser than the available space.

Example if the user select ID 1, the second gridview would show all the other boxes that have usedDimension below 5000:

[image]

And my question is that is it possible to use SQL to achieve that? By using a subquery?

Comment: It's possible by using a new query with a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You are able to use where clause:

```
Select id, (totalDimension - usedDimension) AS available From Box where (totalDimension - usedDimension) < @somevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

set your selected value in a variable adn pass it to the query

```
          select Id,UsedDimension from Box where [UsedDimension]<5000
```